# Unexplicable warning message in MCMClogit / model.matrix.default after R and package update

Tags: r, warnings, model.matrix

After update of R to version 3.6 and update of package `MCMCpack`, I get a warning message I cannot fix in `MCMClogit`.

```
library(MCMCpack)    
y = rbinom(20, 1,0.5)
x = rnorm(20)
m = MCMClogit(y ~ x)
```

Gives

```
Warning message:
In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
```

What is going on?

Comment: Like some other packages, it seems R 3.6 cause some problems. I get no errors with ``R 3.5.3``. Have you try switching version?

Comment: I would guess this would be due to that fact that now in R 3.6.0, "`model.matrix(*, contrasts.arg = CC)` now warns about invalid `contrasts.arg`s" (see the [changelog](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html)). I would actually be surprised if this caused any actual problems for you, other than the annoying warning message. You could turn if off via `suppressWarnings()`, though I would follow @Gainz suggestion to also run the analysis on another R version just to make sure.

Comment: @Gainz Haven't tried it. Will wait for an update of R to see if problem persists.